# PHP Ganon (HTML DOM parser) object issue

Tags: php, object, ganon

This is Ganon: https://code.google.com/p/ganon/

This is my code (see the problem reports in the comments):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include_once("htmlparser.php");
$url = "https://www.origin.com/en-us/store/buy/mirrors-edge/pc-download/base-game/standard-edition";
$html = file_get_dom($url);

//DOCUMENTATION SAYS I CAN USE BOTH FORM
$body1 = $html("div.container.ageGate", 0); //BUT THIS DOESN'T WORK (Function name must be a string in...)
$body2 = $html->select("div.container.ageGate", 0); //THIS WORKS APPARENTLY

$body2->select(".row .span24 h1", 0)->getInnerText(); //THIS SHOULD GET THE CONTENT OF THE GIVEN ELEMENT, BUT IT DOES NOT WORK (Call to a member function select() on a non-object in...)
```

I don't understand why the code doesn't work.

Comment: Would you edit your question to explain how it doesn't work? Edit: ah, it's in comments... :)

Comment: The call on a non-object presumably just means your selector was not found, I guess?

Comment: @halfer I tried to call also `$html->select("div", 0)->getInnerText()` same error...

Comment: Have you tried tracing the `select()` method? What does it do internally?

Comment: @halfer It looks like Ganon supports only one class inside selector... so this works `$body2 = $html->select("div.ageGate", 0);`

Comment: But why does that succeed if a `div` on its own fails? What type does `$html->select("div", 0)` bring back - are you sure the latter is not returning an array rather than `null`?